Why I can't add params in the URL in nextjs 14?
I am using NextJS 14. I want to add a parameter in the url when redirecting to the search page from another page. This means that I want to have the parameter in the url on the search page when I click on a button on another page. Please take a look at my code and give me a solution. Thanks in advance.
I tried the following method, but it is not working.
import { useRouter} from "next/navigation";
const router = useRouter();

const handleSearch = () => {
    router.push(`/search?term=${searchTerm}`);
};

I have the above code in my Navabar.tsx file and call it when the below button is clicked.
<div className="relative text-gray-600 lg:block hidden">
    <input
       type="search"
       name="search"
       placeholder={lang?.header?.search_products}
       className="bg-white h-12 px-5 pr-10  text-sm w-[400px] border-gray-300"
       onChange={(e) => setSearchTerm(e.target.value)}
     />
     <button
        type="submit"
        className="absolute right-0 top-0 mt-4 mr-4"
      >
      <SearchIcon onClick={() => handleSearch()} />
  </button>
</div>

When I click on the above button, it riderect me to the search page with this URL: http://localhost:3000/en/search. But the expected URL is http://localhost:3000/en/search?term=something
My search file route is app/[lang]/(home)/search/page.tsx.

Try passing the 'searchTerm' in the query.
router.push({path: `/search`, query: {term: searchTerm}})

Then, you can access the searched Term using 'router.query.term'

When I click on the button, it gives this error
TypeError: path.startsWith is not a function
